# Mostrar PDF en pagina web

Tags: c#, asp.net

Buenas tardes compañeros, les comento mi situación.

Tengo una pagina en donde muestro varios botones que al momento de dar clic a alguno lo manda a otra pagina donde hay un pdf embebido.

```
        <div class="embed-container">
            <iframe width="560" height="315" src="ruta.pdf" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
        </div>
```

esto me genera que cada botón tenga una pagina a la cual redirigirse,

Mi pregunta es si puedo crear solo una pagina en aspx y dependiendo del botón en que den clic muestre el PDF correspondiente.

Espero me puedan ayudar.

Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes utilizar un actionResult para tus botones.

```
public ActionResult GetPdf(string fileName)
{
    string filePath = "~/Content/files/" + fileName;
    Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=" + fileName);        

    return File(filePath, "application/pdf");
}
```